# use a dropdown list in a datalist and bind from sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, drop-down-menu, datalist

I have a datalist that get data from my sql and i need to bind a dropdownlist in it from other table.
I left join 2 table together and write this code for my data list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dlPricelist" CssClass="width100darsad dropdownlist"  runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("pricelistPrice") %>'>                                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

but it shows prices word by word i mean for example 100 $ shows:

1

0

0

What should I do?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show anything. Give us the code so we can help

Comment: i dont know whay my codes gone!!!

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="dlPricelist" CssClass="width100darsad dropdownlist"  runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("pricelistPrice") %>'>
 </asp:DropDownList>